# Work with external array

Tags: c#-4.0

I would like to write a method that will returns an object and puts it to external array,but array index should be increase after a method was fulfilled.
On next time, when I call method once againe,an object should wrote to neighboring cell in external array.Can you advice me any ideas or show me any examples?Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have correctly understood you question, you should use `List<T>` type for your "external array". It has `Add(T item)` method that allows you to add items exactly the same way as you've described. Let's say your object is of type `Foo`:

```
public void Test()
{
    var externalArray = new List<Foo>();
    var foo1 = MyMethod(externalArray);
    var foo2 = MyMethod(externalArray);
}

public Foo MyMethod(List<Foo> list)
{
    var item = new Foo();
    list.Add(item);
    return item;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.I try to use linked list struct as suggestion.